# Reading Diode Datasheet

Tags: diodes, datasheet

I am learning about Diode and its use (Just get interested in electrical stuff after reading a DIY project), I have been reading information around and want to get more understand on diode especially the datasheet.

[image: Diode Datasheet]

Can someone explain the use of the each characteristic in the datasheet??

Peak Repetitive Reverse Voltage: 50V 
- mean that the current will pass the diode in reverse if the voltage is over 50?

Average Rectified Output Current
- mean maximun current the diode can output? what is T(A)?

Answer (score 3):

Peak Repetitive Reverse Voltage is the "guaranteed" normal reverse voltage across the diode without causing it problems like breakdown - notice that further down it states that peak reverse current is between 5uA and 50uA (at temperature) for this reverse voltage (same as blocking voltage)

Ta is ambient temperature.

Answer (score 3):

> Peak Repetitive Reverse Voltage: 50V - mean that the current will pass the diode in reverse if the voltage is over 50?

Not quite, it means the current **might** pass the diode in reverse if the voltage is over 50. The diode may perform better than this, but it would be unwise to rely on it. You will notice that the 1N4001 to 1N4007 are essentially the same diode. It may be cheaper for the mfg to simply make 1N4007s and mark the poorer performing batches as 1N4001, 1N4002 etc, or even sell higher performing parts under the lower grade part number.

Average rectified output current - yes. Above 1A, look for another diode.

TA is ambient temperature.